# What is wrong with my security here?

Tags: linux, email, security, gmail

I followed [this](http://rianjs.net/2013/08/send-email-from-linux-server-using-gmail-and-ubuntu-two-factor-authentication) method for creating an email address for my desktop (so that I can automate certain emails, etc.) and when I try to test an email I get:

```
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

and got an email from Google saying that

```
Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account < my gmail account >@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.
```

Assuming I followed the directions on this page, should I have gotten this error? Secondarily, I have the option of [lowering my security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66025/what-are-the-dangers-of-allowing-less-secure-apps-to-access-my-google-account) with this account ... but is this bad? It sounds like the only negative aspect of lowering security here is the use of 3rd party apps, but this 'app' is just my desktop that I have fully control over.

Comment: To the close voter - the question is **on-topic** as OP is **using with a desktop client**

Comment: You have no choice, if you want to use the client, you have to allow the connection

Comment: If you read the comments for the article you refer to, multiple people report the same thing. So yes...

Comment: Have you followed the "If you're using two-factor auth" part?